# When a city outbreaks when using the Malaria Historical Disease, does it create one or two outbreak cubes?

Tags: pandemic, pandemic-iberia

In Pandemic Iberia, the [rules](https://images-cdn.zmangames.com/us-east-1/filer_public/c3/62/c362beb7-bb07-4834-92f9-693de3f4eda5/zm7120_pandemic_iberia_rules.pdf) for the Malaria historical disease state:

> When infecting with black, whenever you would put 1 black cube into a city that has no black cubes in it, add 2 black cubes instead.

Does an outbreak create one black cube in the adjacent cities or two?

- **Case for not applying to outbreaks:** There is an Infect step, and the rules for outbreaks are not described in that section, they are in the next section. Furthermore the rules for outbreaks use the word *place*, not the word *infect*:

> Then, place 1 cube of the disease color on every city connected to the city

- **Case for applying to outbreaks:** The rules use the word *whenever*, which implies more than one situation. Additionally, the word infect is not capitalized. Finally, the flavor text on the card says

> **NEW** INFECTIONS ARE MORE SEVERE

We are not sure. How does it work?

<sub>One final thought: not applying to outbreaks makes Malaria sort of toothless and not altogether much more difficult than a basic disease, because in Iberia you can often get away with not cleaning. But this argument is more about balance and less about the text of the rules (perhaps a house rule might be in order?)</sub>

Comment: The tag has been created/added, but it will be auto-reaped unless someone adds a description to it or a second question gets tagged with it.

Answer (score 1):

Infecting and placing disease cubes are different things. It just so happens that infecting often (but not always, as in the case of an outbreak) causes a disease cube to be added.

The rules for Malaria state that you only place an extra cube when infecting. They do not say something like "whenever you would place a cube, place an extra cube".

Rules governing infecting a city:

> To infect a city, place 1 disease cube matching its color onto  the
>   city. If there is a purification token in a region adjacent  to the
>   city, however, remove 1 purification token from an  adjacent region
>   (returning it to the supply) instead of placing a  cube. (If there is
>   more than one adjacent region with a purification  token, the current
>   player decides which token to remove.) If the city already has 3 cubes
>   of this color, do not place a  4th cube. Instead, an outbreak of this
>   disease occurs in the  city (see Outbreaks below). Discard this card
>   to the Infection  Discard Pile.

Rules governing an outbreak:

> When a disease outbreak occurs, move the outbreaks  marker forward 1
>   space on the Outbreaks Track. Then,  place 1 cube of the disease color
>   on every city connected  to the city (or remove a purification token
>   if any). If any of  them already has 3 cubes of the disease color, do
>   not place  a 4th cube in those cities. Instead, in each of them, a
>   chain  reaction outbreak occurs after the current outbreak is done

An infected city is only one for which an infection card is drawn.

Regarding your arguments for the other interpretation:

Use of the word "whenever":
This word is used to declare that it happens whenever an infection card is drawn for an uninfected city. I cant think of any other way to describe it without using "whenever" or a similar word. It does not imply there are other situations.

"Infect" vs "infect":
Doesn't matter. Infect is not a proper noun and was not made into one by the rules.

Flavor text:
Given my interpretation, infections ARE more severe.